# Touchmove event not firing as a Backbone event

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, touch

I'm using backbone.js and I have my events set up like this:

```
events: {
     'touchstart button#target' : 'handleTouchstart',
     'touchmove button#target' : 'handleTouchmove'
},

handleTouchstart: function() {
     console.log('Touched');
},

handleTouchmove: function() {
     console.log('Moving'); // this doesn't fire
}
```

When I touch the button, that method is fired and 'Touched' is printed to the console. But the touch move method won't fire. It happens in multiple places in the document. Is the touchmove event not acknowledged by Backbone?

Comment: The `touchmove` event won't fire on the button if your finger goes outside the button area. You need to listen for the `touchmove` event on the document body.

Comment: Even when I touch inside the button and move inside the button, the event still does not fire.

Comment: It works for me. I'm not sure how you're testing but all I can suggest is that you try to specify a different (larger) element to listen for the `touchmove` event.